# How to delete item and his info in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list:

```
   lst= ['Jason', 999999999, 'jason@live.com', 'Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']
```

I want to delete Jason and the next 2 entries and the following so I´m thinking in this :

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if "Jason" in lst:
        del lst[0]
        del lst[1]
        del lst[2]
    else:
        print("Jason not in lst")
```

Is this correct?

What I´m working with thanks to Tigerhawk is the following:

Original list:

```
 lst = `[['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com'], ['Jason', 999999999, 'jason@live.com']]`

def clean_lst(lst):
    name=str(input("Name you want to delete:")) #With this I get the lst on the 1st paragraph
    lst = sum(lst, [])
    if len(lst)==0:
        print("Empty List")
    elif name in lst:
        idx = lst.index(name)
        del lst[idx:idx+3]
    else: 
        print("Name is not on the list")
```

End result should look like this:

```
lst = `[['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']]`
```

Comment: Why someone voted it down and for two times? The user has given the code and showed what he/she did. That's unfair. If you think that's simple question, then help to answer it, not vote it down.

Comment: Just a tentative suggestion, accept or not depending on what you want to do. Dictionary seems to be a better choice for your data, eg. `dic = {'Jason': {'phone':99999,  'mail':'jason@live.com'}, 'Curt': ...}`, then `if 'Jason' in dic: del dic['Jason']`.

Comment: That is exactly my point...this downvoting thing has to stop..loook I was downvotied twice and i was forced to delete my answer despite I have tested my answer and it worked...This is getting ridiculous and immature...

Comment: I don't even experience these problem that much in the javascript community here..hmm....unfriendly environment with python..hope this improves

Comment: @SyrtisMajor I accept your suggestion but I really want to keep this within lists since I don´t want to overcomplicated the code.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can you review your answer. Thank You

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 updated info

Comment: @Phyti, are you actually saying you want to flatten the list?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no with the command sum I have a flatten list already.

Comment: @Phyti, sum is not how to flatten a list. It is incredibly inefficient, do all original sublists only have three elements?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ok that may be probably the reason why it wasn´t working. The `lst` depends on user previous inputs since it´s him who adds the data

Comment: @Phytim so they can be any size?

Comment: Yes @PadraicCunningham your solution works for delete but since I need to have an if statement in case the name you choose isn´t on `lst` and turn it back on a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have more than one, start from the end of the list and del `i` to `i + 3` if `l[i]` is equal to Jason:

```
l = ['Jason', 999999999, 'jason@live.com', 'Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com', "Jason", "foo", "bar"]

for i in range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):
    if l[i] == "Jason":
        del l[i:i+3]
```

Output:

```
['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']
```

As far as your own code goes, it presumes that `"Jason"` is always the first element even after removing any previous which seems unlikely but only you know for sure.

The most efficient way to do this, is to either create a new list or update the original using a generator function:

```
def rem_jas(l):
    it = iter(l)
    for ele in it:
        if ele == "Jason":
            # skip two elements
            next(it,"")
            next(it, "")
        else:
            yield ele
```

Output:

```
In [30]: l = ['Jason', 999999999, 'jason@live.com', 'Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com', "Jason", "foo", "bar"]

In [31]: l[:] = rem_jas(l)

In [32]: l
Out[32]: ['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']
```

If you can possibly have `Jason` within two elements of another `Jason` then you need to decide what is the appropriate thing to do. If there is always at least 3 spaces then it will be fine.

Based on your edit and the fact you have a list of lists not a flat list, it seems you want to remove each sublist where the `name` appears which makes the code a lost simpler:

```
lst = [['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com'], ['Jason', 999999999, 'jason@live.com']]
from itertools import chain
lst[:] = chain(*(sub for sub in lst if "Jason" not in sub))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']
```

`sum` is not a good way to flatten a list, `itertools.chain` is far more efficient.

If you want to keep the sublists then don't flatten:

```
 lst[:] = (sub for sub in lst if "Jason" not in sub)
 print(lst)
```

Or a hybrid if you have multiple Jasons and need to add a few prints based on conditions:

```
def rem_jas(l, name):
    it = iter(l)
    for ele in it:
        if ele == name:
            # skip two elements
            next(it,"")
            next(it, "")
        else:
            yield ele

def clean_lst(l):
    name = "Jason"
    for sub in l:
        tmp = list(rem_jas(sub, name))
        if tmp:
           yield tmp
        if len(tmp) == len(sub):
           print("{} not in sublist".format(name))


lst[:] = clean_lst(lst)
print(lst)
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: lst = [['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com'], ['Jason', 999999999, 'jason@live.com']]

In [6]: lst[:] = clean_lst(lst)
Jason not in sublist

In [7]: print(lst)
[['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']]
```

And lastly if you want to let the user know which sublist was missing the name:

```
def clean_lst(l):
    name = "Jason"
    for ind, sub in enumerate(l):
        tmp = list(rem_jas(sub, name))
        if tmp:
           yield tmp
        if len(tmp) == len(sub):
           print("{} not in sublist {}".format(name, ind))
```

Comment: Seems like someone don't happy at Christmas.

Comment: @BMW, I reckon there is a lump of coal with someones name on it ;)

Comment: Hmm...the second solution also doesn't work if the `l` is `[999999999, 'jason@live.com', 22222222, 'Jason', 'Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com', 555555,'Jason', 'abc','Jason',"a"]`, but the first one works as the expect.

Comment: @KevinGuan, The footnote to my answer discusses that, it is only an issue if Jason can appear within two places which I doubt is possible from the OP's description  and own logic, using the generator logic is a lot more efficient than creating multiple new lists and doing multiple lookups. There are cases where you could completely empty the list based on certain criteria

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Ah, yep.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the 1st code isn´t working with input, can you please review it with the new info I give on the question. Thank you

Comment: @Phyti, it couldn't work as the input changed from a flat list to a list of lists, I edited the answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham other problem remains that is how do I turn it back into a list of lists like the 1st paragraph lst?

Comment: @Phyti, add exactly what can come in as input and exactly what you want as output to your question. If you want a list of lists then just don't flatten

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Done

Comment: @Phyti, how long can the sublists be and can name appear more than once?

Comment: They basically should be added to the function lst and substitute the initial (1st paragraph) and be printed anytime the user requests with the following command: `print(sorted(lst, key=lambda lst: lst[0], reverse=False))` which inside a `def func(lst):`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply search for the appropriate index and then delete a slice of three entries:

```
lst = ['Jason', 999999999, 'jason@live.com', 'Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']
if 'Jason' in lst:
    idx = lst.index('Jason')
    del lst[idx:idx+3]
```

Result:

```
>>> lst
['Curt', 333333333, 'curt@job.com']
```

Comment: Can you specify the way in which it doesn't work? There certainly are many ways in which code with `raw_input` can fail, but there are also many ways for it to succeed.

Comment: I updated the post to let you know of the code structure.

Comment: @Phyti - You're using a Python 3-style `print()`, and according to the question's tags you're using Python 3. Why do you expect `raw_input` to work?

Comment: sorry I meant  `Input`

Comment: @Phyti - Again, you are using Python 3. `raw_input` does not exist in Python 3.

Comment: But `Input` does like I mentioned above on the question

Comment: Do you mean the fact that you don't return anything, so the new `lst` you assign as a local variable simply disappears?

Comment: "I get an error" tells me nothing. Either explain the current issue further by editing this question, or address a new issue by asking a new question.

Comment: Yes left leaving me with one and only `lst`.

Comment: Either explain the current issue further by editing this question, or address a new issue by asking a new question.